# When to use Clip Output to Graphics Extent in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.

When would one use this check box when exporting a map? I never use it, but I see it.

Here's the check box, it shows up when you're in Layout view and go to File > Export Map:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's used to eliminate any whitespace you may have around your layout in the output file. For example, I have some MXDs set up to print on a specific paper size with specific margins, so that the maps I print can be 3-hole punched or bound without the holes affecting the map window. But sometimes I don't care about that and just want everything to fill the page. That's when you use that checkbox.

Here's the upper-left corner of a map layout with the box unchecked, my whitespace is there:
[image]

And with the box checked, it's clipped to just my map elements:

[image]

I believe ArcGIS just looks for the limits of all map elements (data frames, north arrows, any other graphics or text boxes, etc) and clips the output to that.

Comment: Can you post a screen clip of where this check box exists?

Comment: I added one to the question. It only shows up if you're in Layout view, if you're in Data Frame view it's missing. I'm pretty sure it's in v10.0, I think I remember using it (and it crashing ArcGIS) in v9.x.

Comment: Indeed only in Layout view. I never noticed that. I guess since I don't check it.  I remember seeing it back in 9.3ish?

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot. I couldn't figure out how to add one.

Comment: Thanks Dan C. It does pull all things in layout view - so if you have something outside the view, it draws the box to everything.  I guess that is why it's use didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Jennifer Yeah, I think that's what's causing the little sliver of whitespace you see on the left side of my second screenshot, there's some graphic element sticking out on that side just a hair.

Comment: There's no need for the check box in Data view as exports are all clipped to the extent of the view. I have used this setting for preparing maps for pagination in Illustrator - the extra border can cause masking problems when laying multiple elements against each other in desktop publishing.