# Replicate 'Clip Output to Graphics Extent' when exporting with arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcpy

Sometimes I use the check box ['Clip Output to Graphics Extent'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/arcgis-10-clip-output-to-graphics-extent) when exporting using the UI.  I currently have a largish batch of mxd's that I want to export with this button checked.  I am using the [ExportToPNG](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopng.htm) for the batch export but can't see how to set the 'Clip Output to Graphics Extent'.  Thus all my outputs have white borders.

Based on my googling this isn't possible but can someone please confirm?  What are my alternatives for clipping white space from layout views?

Example with Clip Output to Graphics Extent **unchecked**:
[image: Border]

Example with Clip Output to Graphics Extent **checked**:
[image: No Border]

Comment: Can you provide a image example of an output with a white border?

Comment: @artwork21 I can, but I need to mock up something not confidential and find a web hosting site my work doesn't block.

Comment: @artwork21 example images added.

Answer (score 2):

For those that don't know what this option does, see [When to use Clip Output to Graphics Extent in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/arcgis-10-clip-output-to-graphics-extent)

There a [geonet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/16736) about this missing functionality in arcpy. The workaround offered there is to use masking layer.

> The masking layer can "white out" the zone outside the area of
>   interest before the export is done.
>
> This can be done in the user interface with Data Driven Pages using
>   page definitions (via the definition query tab).
>
> Or it can be done with arcpy.mapping in a similar way but by
>   automating the updating of definition queries.